# WPF ListView item controls alignemnt

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, wpf-controls

Im very new to WPF and im creating a ListView like the image below:
[image]

My issue is that i want the images of each item (blue bed img) to start at the beginning of the item just like the TextBlock but to keep the hierarchy the same (image on top , text on bottom)

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MenuPick.Windows.Views.Wards"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MenuPick" Height="720" Width="1200"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FileItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="207" >
                            <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="2.5"/>
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="207*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="129*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="lvWards" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="608" Margin="0,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1185" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComputer, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FileItemStyle}">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel>
                        <Image DockPanel.Dock="TOP" Source="..\Resources\Images\icon-ward.png" Width="55" Height="36" />
                        <TextBlock  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"  Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Green" Width="155" Height="180"/>

                    </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Set same `DockPanel.Dock` for both `Image` and `TextBlock` or what is the problem?

Comment: Setting the same `DockPanel.Dock` doesn't change anything. The image still has a padding on the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are using `DockPanel`, but a normal `Grid` should do:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/ >
        <RowDefinition/ >
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" ... />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" .../>
</Grid>
```

You could try to use `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` (for `Image`) with `DockPanel` as you have now, not sure in outcome, perhaps you have to host `Image` inside top-docked `Grid` for this to work.